# mysql statment SELECT INSERT INTO tip

Tags: mysql

My statement is correct missing one Column, but it does not insert the hashtag from table `trending_topics` into the `rss` table  based on order.

Any adjust can help me with my statement.

```
INSERT INTO rss (id,hashtag,total)
SELECT
  hashtag,
  SUM(count) AS total
FROM `trending_topics`
WHERE lang=0
  AND hashtag !=     ''
  AND date >= date_sub(left(now(), 10), interval 1 day)
GROUP BY hashtag order by total desc;;
```

My insert into table (`rss`) looks like:

```
  id  hashtag  total
  1    null    55
  2    null    22
```

Comment: use `insert into rss(hashtag, total)`? I guess id is auto increment?

Comment: yes its , consider i dont have " total" at  `trending_topics`

Comment: then I think I do not understand your question - you dont have the column, but you try to select it?

Comment: i just edit my question please take a look ,  im using this statement to get " total"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the datatypes and your example sql etc. are correct (and there is a hashtag returned by the select) then the following should work (**remove the id** in the insert into statement)

```
INSERT INTO rss (hashtag,total)
SELECT
  hashtag,
  SUM(count) AS total
FROM `trending_topics`
WHERE lang=0
  AND hashtag !=     ''
  AND date >= date_sub(left(now(), 10), interval 1 day)
GROUP BY hashtag order by total desc;
```

Comment: You can remove the `ORDER BY` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The number of inserted fields should match the number of fields specified at `INSERT INTO table_name (field list)`

```
INSERT INTO rss (hashtag,total)
SELECT
  hashtag,
  SUM(count) AS total
```

Comment: consider i dont have " total" at trending_topics